# Cannot enter data in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have built a few models and registered them with django admin

```
admin.site.register({Cat,Comment,User,Bet,Bid})
```

But the Cat and Comment don't have any fields for me to add data in(see image). does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
[image: Nowhere to add data]

```
class User(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
    user = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank=True)
    passwd = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField('date joined',null=True, blank=True)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=5,max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    bitaddress = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    img=models.ImageField(upload_to = 'img/user/')


#this is a bet like "I think that the Lions willwin the Superbowl"
class Bet(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.position
    position = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField('date published',null=True, blank=True)
    cat= models.ForeignKey("Cat",null=True,blank=True)

#lookup field for category - maybe dManyToManyo subcategories
class Cat(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cat_name
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)#,null=True, blank=True)



class Bid(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
    user = models.ForeignKey("User",null=True, blank=True)
    amt = models.DecimalField('date published',max_digits=15, decimal_places=5,null=True, blank=True)
    bet=models.ForeignKey("Bet",null=True, blank=True)



class Comment(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text
    user = models.ForeignKey("User",null=True, blank=True)
    bet=models.ForeignKey("Bet",null=True, blank=True)
    text=models.TextField()#null=True,blank=True)
    #parent=models.ForeignKey-->another comment
```

Comment: Can you just do `admin.site.register(Cat)` and see what happens ?

Comment: Same problem if I do admin.site.register(Cat)

Comment: just out of curiosity, (It should not really matter), but does this work? `admin.site.register(Cat, CatAdmin)` and `class CatAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): pass`

Answer (score 0):

Register the the models you want in the admin site sone at a time:

```
admin.site.register(Cat)
admin.site.register(Comment)
admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(Bet)
admin.site.register(Bid)
```

Comment: Did you follow the steps in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/ ?